# How to create 'user typing' in socket.io with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

These days I create advanced chat app. But I cant solve this problem now. How Can I do `'user typing'` in `socket.io` and `react`. 
This is my page when I write message:

```
import {Input, Button } from 'antd'
import { useConversation } from "../../conversation";
import { SendOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import {Auth} from '../../context'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {useSocket} from '../../socket'

export default function Bottom(){

    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [ok, setok] = useState(false)
    const {sendMessage, currentConversation} = useConversation()
    const {user} = Auth()
    const socket = useSocket()
    useEffect( ()=>{
      if(text.length > 0 && !ok ) { 
        socket.emit('send-typing', {currentConversation, user })
        setok(true)
      }
      if(text.length === 0 && ok){
        socket.emit('stop-typing', {currentConversation, user})
        setok(false)
      }  
    },[text] )

    function handleSubmit() {
        const {recipients, ...other} = currentConversation;
        sendMessage(
            currentConversation.recipients.map(r => r._id),
            {recipients: recipients.push(user), ...other},
          text
        )
        setok(false)
        socket.emit('stop-emit', {currentConversation, user})
        setText('')
    }

    return (<div className="open_bottom">
          <Input.Group compact >
            <Input.TextArea placeholder="Write message" value={text} style={{ resize: 'none' }} onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)} 
              onPressEnter={handleSubmit}
            />
            <Button type="primary" onClick={handleSubmit} > <SendOutlined/> </Button>
          </Input.Group>
    </div>)
}
```

This is my backend. Its work successfully:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

    const id = socket.handshake.query.id
    socket.join(id)
    console.log("user ", id, " connected" );
    socket.on('send-message', async ( {recipients, sender , current, text}, callback )=>{
        recipients.forEach(recipient => {
            socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit('receive-message', {
              current, sender, text
            })
        })
        let err=false;
        try {
            const nw = new Messages({ about: current._id, sender: sender._id, text, who_deleted:[], readers:[] });
            await nw.save();
        } catch (e) {
            err=true;
        }
        callback({err: err})
    });
    socket.on('send-typing', ({currentConversation, user})=>{
        console.log("typing ", currentConversation._id);
        currentConversation.recipients.forEach( r=>{
            socket.broadcast.to( r ).emit('get-typing', { current: currentConversation, writer: user })
        })
    })
    socket.on('stop-typing', ({currentConversation, user})=>{
        console.log("stop-typing ", currentConversation._id);
        
        currentConversation.recipients.forEach( r=>{
            socket.broadcast.to( r ).emit('dur-typing', { current: currentConversation, writer: user })
        })
    })
   
    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        console.log("user ", id, " disconnect");
    })
})
```

Problem here: `socket.on('dur-typing', ...)` and `socket.on('get-typing', ...)` cannot work. Really words I didnt understand why cannot work or cannot get data. I didnt understand where I must use `socket.off`. Please help fix this problem

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState, useMemo, useCallback} from 'react'

import {useSocket} from './socket'

import {Auth} from './context'

const ConversationsContext = React.createContext()

export function useConversation(){
    return useContext(ConversationsContext)
}

export default function ConversationProvider( {children} ){
    
    const socket = useSocket()

    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([])
    const [currentConversation, setCurrentConversation] = useState(null)
    const [typing, setTyping] = useState([])

    const [msg, setMsg] = useState(false)
    const [typ, setTyp] = useState(false)
    const [dur, setDur] = useState(false)

    const {user} = Auth()
    const addMessageToConversation = useCallback(({ current, sender, text}) => {
      setMsg(true)  
      setConversations(prevConversations => {
          let madeChange = false
          const newMessage = { sender, text }
          const newConversations = prevConversations.map(conversation => {
            if( conversation._id === current._id ){
              madeChange = true
              return {
                ...conversation,
                messages: [...conversation.messages, newMessage]
              }
            }
    
            return conversation
          })
          if (madeChange) {
            return newConversations
          } else {
            return [
              ...prevConversations,
              { ...current, messages: [newMessage] }
            ]
          }
        })
      }, [setConversations])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (socket == null) return
        setMsg(false)
        setTyp(false)
        setDur(false)
        socket.on('receive-message', addMessageToConversation)
        socket.on('get-typing', (current, writer)=>{
          console.log("get-typing", current, writer);
          setTyp(true)
          setTyping( prev=>{
            let ok = false;
            const nw = prev.map( i=>{
              if( i.current._id === current._id ){
                ok = true;
                return {current, writers: [...i.writers, writer]}
              }
              else return i;
            } )
            if(ok) return nw;
            else return [...prev, {current, writers: [writer]}]
          })
        })
        socket.on('dur-typing', (current, writer)=>{
          setDur(true)
          console.log("dur-typing", current, writer);
          setTyping( prev=>{
            const nw = prev.map( i=>{
              if( i.current._id === current._id ){
                const wr =  i.writers.filter( t =>{
                  return t._id !== writer._id
                } ) ;

                return {current, writers: wr }
              }
              else return i;
            } )
            return nw;
          })
        })
        return () =>{
          if(msg) socket.off('receive-message')
          // if(typ) socket.off('get-typing')
          // if(dur) socket.off('dur-typing')
        }

    }, [socket, addMessageToConversation, typing])


    console.log(typing);
    // useEffect(()=>{
    //   if(currentConversation === null || socket==null ) return
    //   socket.emit('read-message', {_id: currentConversation._id, user: user._id}, ({err})=>{
    //     if(err) alert( "Cannot update!" );
    //   })

    // }, [socket, currentConversation ])

    function sendMessage(recipients,  current,  text) {
        socket.emit('send-message', { recipients, sender: user, current, text }, ({err})=>{
          if(err) alert(" Try again! ")
        });
        addMessageToConversation({ current,  sender:user , text })
    }

    function rnd_arr(arr) {
        var currentIndex = arr.length,  randomIndex;
      
        while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex--;
      
          [arr[currentIndex], arr[randomIndex]] = [arr[randomIndex], arr[currentIndex]];
        }
        return arr;
    }

    const formatted = useMemo ( ()=> conversations.map( i=>{
        const { recipients, groupName, ...other } = i;
        const all = recipients.filter( t=>{
            return t._id !== user._id
        })
        const logos = rnd_arr(all)
        let l = [], name = ""

        l.push( logos[0].logo )
        name = logos[0].username

        if( logos.length > 1 ){
            l.push(logos[1].logo)
            if( groupName.length > 0 ) name = groupName
            else name += ',...'
        }

        return {recipients: all, name, logo: l, isGroup: all.length > 1,groupName, isAdmin: i.admins.includes(user._id), ...other }
    } ), [conversations])
    
    const t = useMemo( ()=>{
      if( currentConversation === null ) return null;
      else  return formatted[formatted.findIndex( t => {
        return ( t._id === currentConversation._id );
      } )]
    }, [formatted,currentConversation] )


    const value = {
        setConversations,
        conversations: formatted,
        setCurrentConversation,
        currentConversation: t,
        sendMessage,
        typing
    }

    return (
        <ConversationsContext.Provider value={value}>
            { children }
        </ConversationsContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely at this wall of code, but a `useEffect` function that sets up socket event listeners should probably one run once, i.e. have an empty dependency array.

Comment: Which line this? and how can i do?

Comment: The useEffect in your Conversation Provider has `[socket, addMessageToConversation, typing]` as dependency array, meaning each time `typing` is updated the function runs again. Probably not supposed to happen, since the function sets up socket listeners. (also, if you have to ask which line, I have to wonder who wrote that code?)

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: No. I solved this problem

Comment: How did you solve it? Could you post your solution?